# Index of ideals in rings of integers in number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be the ring of integers of a number field, or more generally, a finite index subring of it, and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Is there exist a good bound for the index $[R:P^n]$ in terms of $n$ and $[R:P]$?. For example, is it true that $[R:P^n]\leq [R:P]^n?$.

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, the index of an ideal in a ring of algebraic integers is the norm of that ideal? If so, then the equality in fact holds? Or I mis-understood something?

Comment: The index of an ideal is the index as a subgroup

Comment: And I mean that index is [the norm of that ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm#Absolute_norm). Of course, rendering an inequality as an equality sounds kind of like cheating, but this is one of the first definitions that I leanrt about norms, so that it is quite natural to me. Per chance you can tell us what your definition of the norms is? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!, so the answer is yes and we obtain equality in the case that $R$ is exactly the ring of integers $O$ of a number field. If $R$ is a subring of $O$ of finite index then we probably obtain inequality.

Comment: If $R$ is a subring of $\mathfrak O$, then $[R,P^n]=[\mathfrak O:P^n]/[\mathfrak O:R]=[\mathfrak O:P]^n/[\mathfrak O:R]=(\dfrac{[\mathfrak O:P]}{[\mathfrak O:R]})^n([\mathfrak O:R])^{n-1}$, hence the result, in the converse direction, as $[\mathfrak O:R]\ge1$. As a consequence, we can find a bound, if the ring $R$ is fixed: i.e. $[R:P]^n[\mathfrak O:R]^{n-1}$.P.S. Sorry for deleting in order to edit it after $5$ minutes.

Comment: Observe that $P$ is ideal in $R$ but not in $O$.

Comment: Well, even though $P$ is not an ideal in $\mathfrak O$, it is still an $R$-module in it. As an $R$ module, there is thus an index $[\mathfrak O,P]$.